# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found. in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new at android studio , I gradled my application from eclipse mars and imported it to android studio,but it shows following error.I have already followed so many answers but could not get succeed,can any one tell what are the issues , i am facing here . Thanks in advance!

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"




    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your top level build.gradle ?

Comment: @Selvin i am new with android studio,i am not getting what you asking

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

instead of only android

Comment: still same error.....:(